# Negation of a statement

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

The question asks us to negate the following statement.

Jackie eats sweets, if she is not hungry.

This is a basic if (p), then (q) statement whose negation will simply be p and ~q, but the solution manual gives the following answer:
Jackie ate sweets though she was not hungry.
Is this solution incorrect (because this implies existence of p and q simultaneously) or is there a flaw in my understanding?

Comment: The book is wrong as @Bumble's response indicates.

Comment: Since when was 'though' a logical connective ? ' If ... then'. 'If and only if', 'and', 'or', 'not'. These I recognise but not 'though'. Russell eliminated 'but'' as a logical connective : 'She was poor but she was happy' can be replaced without loss by 'She was poor and she was happy. Their truth-conditions are identical. Colloquially, of course, matters are different and 'though' has a distinctive role - but not in logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you are just starting to learn logic, it is likely that you are being taught about the conditionals known as material implications. These are usually the first conditionals that you are taught when studying logic, though there are many others. Material implication only works well when used with simple propositions and leads to apparently paradoxical examples when stretched to fit less simple ones. If the conditional in your example is interpreted as a material implication, it is "if Jackie is not hungry then Jackie eats sweets". The negation of a material implication is the antecedent conjoined with the negation of the consequent, so its negation would be "Jackie is not hungry and Jackie does not eat sweets". The answer you have been given: "Jackie ate sweets though she was not hungry" is not correct.

If we were doing some slightly more advanced logic, we might observe that "Jackie eats sweets, if she is not hungry" is better represented as a quantified sentence, along the lines of "on all occasions when Jackie is not hungry she eats sweets". The negation of this might be "sometimes Jackie is not hungry and does not eat sweets".

Answer (score 3):

The nominal solution is incorrect.

The if-then form of the statement is: If Jackie is not hungry, then she eats sweets (if not-H, then S). Then equivalent of (if A, then B) is (not-A or B). In this example, there is a double negation (not-(not-H), so the equivalent becomes: Hungry or Sweets (H or S).

The negation is (not-(H or S)), which, by DeMorgan's, is (not-H and not-S); Jackie is not hungry and she does not eat sweets. This statement is the solution.

The book's solution says: Jackie is not hungry and she eats sweets (not-H and S). Working backwards from that statement, the negation is (not-(not-H and S)); its equivalent is (H or not-S). Then the original statement would have been (If not-H, then not-S): If Jackie is not hungry, then she does not eat sweets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider what this really means:

"Jackie eats sweets, if she is not hungry." doesn't include information about Jackie not eating sweets. It's a proposition that starts with eating sweets and concludes than, that she's hungry.

Each time when Jackie eats sweets, she is not hungry.

The negation:

There's one time (hence the past form) when Jackie ate sweets, even though she wasn't hungry.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we simply use common sense in the statements negation the statements truth could only come from observation but it is an assumption. It contains a nature in its content which is contradictory ie eating when not hungry question the nature of the truth of the observation. The negation "Jakie does not eat sweets if she is hungry" is the common sense negation and results in a similar contradiction in the meaning of the content and maintains the possible truth or assumption in the observation. The logic applied is not an analysis in the nature of the determination of the contradiction in the statement and the negation, or the truth of the observation the statement comes from, but in the negation of the structure and syntax of the language the statement is a composition of.

Comment: You are right in saying that often with natural language conditionals we can contradict a claim "if A then B" with "if A then not B". Some logics, such as connexive logic, have conditionals that work like this. But the OP does say they are starting to learn logic: introductory textbooks usually begin with the material implication conditional. The contradictory of the material implication is "A and not B".